# uploading file to specific folder in S3 using boto3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Everything with my code works. The only pitfall I am currently facing is that I cannot specify the folder within the S3 bucket that I would like to place my file in. Here is what I have:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/'+filename, '<bucket-name>', filename)
```

I have tried both:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/'+filename, '<bucket-name>/folder/', filename)
```

and:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/'+filename, '<bucket-name>', '/folder/'+filename)
```

if anyone has any tips on how to direct this to a specific folder (if this is possible) please let me know!

Comment: S3  is a object store, it doesn't deal with "folder name". The whole "path" must be use as part of the key name.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You do not need to pass the Key value as an absolute path. The following should work:

```
upload_file('/tmp/' + filename, '<bucket-name>', 'folder/{}'.format(filename))
```

Answer (score 11):

I figured out my problem. I had the right idea with the `/folder/` option in the key parameter area, however, I did not need the first `/` Thank you all! This is essentially the same idea as hjpotter92's suggestion above.

Answer (score 8):

## Use this for python 3.x

```
s3.upload_file(file_path,bucket_name, '%s/%s' % (bucket_folder,dest_file_name))
```

Comment: this worked for me. I used another s3 function (`s3.upload_fileobj`) ad it worked as well without any issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `put_object` in the place of `upload_file`:

```
file = open(r"/tmp/" + filename)
response = s3.meta.client.Bucket('<bucket-name>').put_object(Key='folder/{}'.format(filename), Body=file)
```

Comment: this worked for me although my syntax looks a bit different : s3.Bucket("bucketname").put_object(Key='public/' + key, Body=data)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method that will take care of nested directory structure, and will be able to upload a full directory using boto

```
def upload_directory():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(settings.LOCAL_SYNC_LOCATION):
        nested_dir = root.replace(settings.LOCAL_SYNC_LOCATION, '')
        if nested_dir:
            nested_dir = nested_dir.replace('/','',1) + '/'

        for file in files:
            complete_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            file = nested_dir + file if nested_dir else file
            print "[S3_UPLOAD] Going to upload {complete_file_path} to s3 bucket {s3_bucket} as {file}"\
                .format(complete_file_path=complete_file_path, s3_bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET, file=file)
            s3_client.upload_file(complete_file_path, settings.S3_BUCKET, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try it:**

```html
s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename=filename_and_full_path, Bucket=my_bucket, Key=prefix_key_plus_filename_only)
```